# Can I keep two terminals running at the same time with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipc

I'm just getting started with python these days (Got almost 60% of Codecademy's course) and I decided to learn by myself with a text arpg.

Now I'm stuck in one part: I want the player to be able to put commands while the game is running and at the same time to keep the fights script as well.

Does Python has any way to make this happen? If there is any part of the docs around this theme I would appreciate. If this has already been answered, link the question please, sorry, but I did not find it.

EDIT: The game is basically a automatic growth system. What I want is to make one cmd to run and show the progress of the fights (user vs enemies) and another to show the user's character informations (money, itens...) and to be able to recieve commands from the user. Everything in real time, and without the need to kill one of these processes.

Comment: Why can't he run another terminal simultaneously?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Python, but with your desktop environment/terminal emulator... honestly, I'm not even sure exactly what you want or even *why* you would want it...

Comment: You can modify code when game is running but it doesn't change running game - you will have to restart game to see modifications.

Comment: You should write a client/server arrangement. Two programs. Maybe use `sockets` to setup one terminal as your server and also the command window and have another terminal run a client running the fights scripts. Then they could pass messages back and forth. The examples will assume that they are on separate computers, but they can be on the same comptuer and just use 'localhost' as the server name. Make sure the port you use is open and is also open on the firewall. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html

Comment: Look into the `socket` module. Some basic local server can achieve what you need.

Comment: Welcome to *Inter Process Communication*! That is an interesting question that is only loosely related to Python: IPC are provided at OS level, some can be dedicated to one single OS (COM/DCOM/.NET for Microsoft) others are more portable (TCP/IP sockets). My advice: explore it with test only applications before trying to include it in any serious program. And include the security point of view early in your thinkings, because it does matter in IPC...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thank you, I will read and study about that subject and see what I can do to achieve my objective.

Comment: @RobertB Thank you, once a friend of mine said something like this to me but i did not found any info of it in Python. I'll read and see if I can do it